# Simple php for loop based on location url

Tags: php, for-loop, variables

I'm new to PHP but due to a family bereavement I have inherited a website with bespoke CMS and trying to modify a loop of staff members to only show results if the staff in the loop are from a certain location/office. I'm sure it's REALLY simple if you have PHP experience.

I have urls with the office at the end i.e.
**www.mydomain.com/staff/London** or **www.mydomain.com/staff/Bristol**

and am using the following to get the current office (from the URL):

```
$currentOffice = substr(strrchr(curPageURL(), "/"), 1);
echo $currentOffice;
```

The staff members in the CMS list have a field to choose which office they're in. The staff location is in a table called **'inlineItemData_staffListSummary'** in a row called **'office'**. At the moment, I have the full list displaying with the following PHP loop.

```
<?php
   $myListItems = new DB;
   $myListItems->table = $myListItemGroup->getValue("tableName", 0);
   $c = 0;  
   $numInRow = 3;
   $numListItems = $myListItems->numRows();
   for($i = 0; $i < $numListItems; $i++){   
         include($myListItemTemplate->getValue("frontEndTemplate", 0).".inc.php");  
   }
?>
```

I can output the office names in the loop using:

```
$myListItems->getValue("office", $i)
```

How would I adapt this to just loop through offices from the $currentOffice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try something like `for($i = 0; $i < $numListItems; $i++){   
  if ($myListItems->getValue("office", $i) == $currentOffice) {
         include($myListItemTemplate->getValue("frontEndTemplate", 0).".inc.php");  
}   }`. It should only output that row if the office value matches the currentOffice value. Without seeing further info or actual data that's my best guess.

Comment: Also you didn't tell us what the CMS was or point to any documentation (or failing that, show us what the classes do), so that we could understand the various custom function calls and object structures (which might then point us to a better / more efficient way of doing it, e.g. only retrieving relevant results to begin with, rather than simply excluding them from the printout).